# User name property is null in Blazor Server AuthenticationStateProvider?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm working on the Blazor Server-side and I want to access the windows user name. I tried doing this, as per the documentation, using the `AuthenticationStateProvider` object. The issue is that the User Name property is null when I run the solution in Release mode. In Express mode it's working fine, I can get the User Name property, in release mode the value is null.

This is the AuthenticationStateProvider object:

```cs
       public class Authenticator
    {
        public readonly AuthenticationStateProvider _auth;

        public Authenticator(AuthenticationStateProvider authenticationStateProvider)
        {
            _auth = authenticationStateProvider;
        }
    }
```

I inject it in `Startup.cs` :

```cs
services.AddScoped<Authenticator>();
```

I enabled windows authentication:

```
     "iisSettings": {
        "windowsAuthentication": true,
        "anonymousAuthentication": false,
        "iisExpress": {
          "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:49349",
          "sslPort": 0
        }
      }
```

This is how I use the object:

```
return _auth.GetAuthenticationStateAsync().Result.User.Identity.Name.Substring(3);
```

I also enabled WebSocketProtocol:

[image]

The Name property of the User object is null, only in release mode, in normal Debug mode on IIS Express, it works as expected.

I use ASP.NET CORE 3.1 with VisualStudio 16.9.4. I also have this issue on Windows Server 2012 after I publish the app on ISS.

EDIT 1: I also have the same issue when using IHttpContextAccessor with Blazor-Server. It gets the user name in IIS Express but in Release mode the Name is null.

EDIT 2: The issue appears when I run the app with the application name instead of IIS Express. From what I read on the internet, this is using Kestrel server behind.

Comment: I think you have problem in your cookie settings in Startup.cs, I had the same problem and solved it by setting cookie settings in services.ConfigureApplicationCookie and set the options.ExpireTimeSpan

Comment: I tried adding 
            services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
            });
in Startup.cs, I have the same issue.

Comment: I see, but you need to add them completely and in order, I write it in a new answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else will face this issue, I managed to make it work by installing ASP.NET Core 5.0 Runtime (v5.0.6) - Windows Hosting Bundle and URL Rewrite Module. I also added full rights on publish folder to NETWORK and IIS_IUSRS users and modified IIS web app authorization and disabled everything except windows authorization.

The issue seems to be related to IIS Server not being able to read website Authorization settings or the solution webconfig file. The weird thing is that on the server itself there was no error in IIS whatsoever, but the error appeared when I run the application on the local IIS Server.

Answer (score 1):

```
 // Add Identity  Order = 1 !important
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(options =>
        {
            options.Password.RequiredLength = ConfigIdentity.Password_RequiredLength;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = ConfigIdentity.Password_RequireLowercase;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = ConfigIdentity.Password_RequireUppercase;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = ConfigIdentity.Password_RequireNonAlphanumeric;
            options.Password.RequireDigit = ConfigIdentity.Password_RequireDigit;
        }).AddUserManager<UsersManager>().AddRoleManager<RolesManager>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        // Database Contexts Order = 2 !important
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(ServiceLifetime.Transient);

        // 3 : Cookie Options  
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });
        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Error/AccessDenied";
            options.Cookie.Name = "MyAPP";
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
            options.LoginPath = "/";
            //options.ReturnUrlParameter = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.ReturnUrlParameter;
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        });



services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddServerSideBlazor().AddCircuitOptions(options => { options.DetailedErrors = true; });
        services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, RevalidatingIdentityAuthenticationStateProvider<IdentityUser>>();
```